# Post data from one server to another server using PERL

Tags: perl

Assuming abc.pl is a file in server1 and xyz.pl is a file present in server2.

How can I post data(variable,arrays,hashes etc) from abc.pl to xyz.pl?

Also, LWP::UserAgent post() method consider html forms. So I guess I cannot use that lib for my issue.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: When you say "post", do you refer to the http POST method, or is it just sending the data in any way over the network?

Comment: I am just going to go out on a limb and say check out Storable on the CPAN.

Comment: @SzG just sending data. not a http POST.

Answer (score 1):

Below I'll highlight the key expressions so you know which modules/functions to look up.
I'd use the textual `Data::Dumper` as the format for transferring data.

The key steps on the receiving side, xyz.pl:

- open a TCP `socket`, `bind` to an unused port and `listen` for incoming connections
- `accept` the new connection
- read data from the connection's socket
- when client's closed the connection, `eval` the received string, but only after you've verified it's just a variable assignment and not some malicious code
- the received data will be available as $VAR1, [$VAR2, etc].

The key steps on the sending side, abc.pl

- open a TCP socket, `connect` to port on the other machine
- `print Dumper(<data>);` into the socket
- close the socket

Comment: “*but only after you've verified it's […] not some malicious code*” – hello, halting problem. Executing any code received from a client sounds like a bad idea (`Safe` makes this safer, but still…). Serialization formats that don't need `eval` (JSON, YAML) might be preferable. As a bonus, they avoid Perl lock-in.